# Writing a sentence being less ambiguous

Tags: ambiguity, syntactic-analysis, antecedents

I have following paragraph with two corrections.

A- In the 1980s the largest single provider of day care for children was the federal government, which offered

B- The federal government was the largest single provider of day care for children in the 1980s, which offered

child care, health, and educational services to hundreds of thousands of children from poor households through the Head Start program and which supported private day-care facilities through child-care tax credits, state block grants, and tax breaks for employers who subsidized day-care services.

I want to know why A is correct, shouldn't which be pointing to the Federal Gov't

Comment: Because it's reasonable to say that "the 1980s offered…" and if that's not what you mean, you're advised to make that as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example B sounds like it was the 1980s which offered childcare etc.

Generally, 'which' should follow the thing it is referring to, as in Example A.

The correct way to write Example B would be:

> The federal government was the largest single provider of day care for
>   children in the 1980s, offering ..etc